# Initialize a container with iterator range of container with different type

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Let's say we have `std::set<int>` and we want to create a `std::vector<int>` with all values from that set:

```
std::set<int> set;
std::vector<int> vec( set.begin(), set.end() );
```

This is simple and elegant. But let's say I have a `std::map<std::string,int>` and I want to copy all values to `std::vector<int>`. Unfortunately there is no constructor, that accepts range of iterators and converter function. Why there is no such constructor provided? Is there another simple and elegant way to initialize one container with different type values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use transform iterators:

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int, double> m;
    auto f = [](auto&& pair) { return pair.second; };
    std::vector<double>(boost::make_transform_iterator(m.begin(), f),
                        boost::make_transform_iterator(m.end(), f));
}
```

Alternatively, use boost::adaptors:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int, double> m;
    auto range = boost::adaptors::values(m);
    std::vector<double>(range.begin(), range.end());
}
```

Or the same as above:

```
    auto v = boost::copy_range<std::vector<double> >(boost::adaptors::values(m));
```

Note that using vector's range constructor is more efficient than a solution involving `back_inserter`.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the "pipe" operator when using boost adaptors `auto range = m | boost::adaptors::values;`

Comment: @Alan I prefer function call operator for function calls, and it is shorter to type (` | ` vs `()`).

Answer (score 2):

With [`boost::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html):

```
#include <functional>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

std::map<std::string, int> m{ {"a", 1}, {"b", 2} };
auto second = std::mem_fn(&std::map<std::string, int>::value_type::second);

std::vector<int> vec(boost::make_transform_iterator(std::begin(m), second)
                   , boost::make_transform_iterator(std::end(m), second));
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95e2dcd723505a46)

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter (not me) didn't yet have time to write a comment and is still writing it

Comment: Not me, but calling through `std::mem_fn` would likely not be inlined.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid that's gonna be pretty damn long comment

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` has another memory model, storing values as `std::pair`. Unpacking these isn't the job of a constructor. You can create your vector, [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) memory equal to the map [size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/size) and [iterate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin) over map pairs to push your integers to the back of your vector. `std::transform` slims that.

Comment: `std::set` also has another memory model, that does not stop me from initailizing a vector from range of it.

Comment: Because your set iterators return just the expected interger, a map returns a pair which can't be casted to the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is using range based cycles or for_each function.