# set difference between keys of a HashTable and a HashSet

Tags: set, adapter, nim-lang

How to perform a set-difference operation between a "view of the keys from a HashTable" and a HashSet in nim ?

Conceptually:

```
import tables, sets, sequtils

var a = initTable[int, string]()
var b: HashSet[int]
b.init(4)

a[0] = "a"
a[1] = "b"

b.incl(0)
b.incl(1)
b.incl(2)
b.incl(3)

var diff = b - toset(toseq(a.keys))
echo diff # {2, 3}
```

this works (*and it was hard to make work, the compiler gives misleading messages. e.g. try to remove `toseq` above, it says "undeclared field: 'keys'" wow.*)
But of course, this is useless, I'll loop and make the difference myself in this state of things.
What we need is an allocation-less method that works directly with the hashset/hashtable. eg:

```
var diff = b - a.keys
```

or at worst:

```
var diff = b - HashSetView(a.keys)
```

which would create an adapter object form the keys iterator to suit the `-` procedure which probably accepts only sets.

Possible ?

EDIT:
In fact I just remembered what has been floating in my head, it is the `boost::transform_iterator` concept.
[Initialize a container with iterator range of container with different type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377304/initialize-a-container-with-iterator-range-of-container-with-different-type)
This is why in C++'s design, every algorithm/stdlib function takes a range (2 iters) and not reference to the containers themselves as often as possible. This is a form of duck typing.
On second thought my problem here seems to be that the set difference procedure does not work with iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for seems to be solved nicely by Nim's metaprogramming and UFCS facilities:

```nim
proc `-`[K, V](a: HashSet[K], b: Table[K, V]): HashSet[K] =
  result = a

  for k in b.keys:
    result.excl k


var diff = b - a
```

As you suspected, this is going to be more performant than allocating a completely new sequence only to discard it for a set. There does not seem to be a built-in way to do what you want to accomplish though.

The `undeclared field: "keys"` error makes sense in the context that [`keys`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tables.html#keys.i,Table[A,B]) is [an *inline* iterator](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#iterators-and-the-for-statement-first-class-iterators) and not a field, however this error message certainly could be more informative. If you wish to use an arbitrary iterator, it seems like you will have to [wrap it in a closure](https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/2027), though it may introduce some overhead as a result.

With `toClosure` from the [nim-iterutils](https://github.com/def-/nim-iterutils) package:

```nim
template toClosure*(i): auto =
  ## Wrap an inline iterator in a first-class closure iterator.
  iterator j: type(i) {.closure.} =
    for x in i:
      yield x
  j

proc `-`[K](a: HashSet[K], b: iterator): HashSet[K] =
  result = a

  for k in b():
    result.excl k


var diff = b - toClosure(a.keys)
```

If you don't need the complete result, then yielding the difference is likely to have even greater performance.

```nim
iterator without_keys[K, V](a: HashSet[K], b: Table[K, V]): K =
  for k in a.items:
    if not b.has_key(k):
      yield k

for k in b.without_keys(a):
  echo k
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The thread you pointed https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/2027 also mentions that using closures is 10 times slower than creating a redundant sequence. The custom difference procedure is better, and even great if we make it an iterator that yields instead of creating a new set. But having to write ad-hoc stuff means the stdlib is insufficient, or badly designed no ?

Comment: @v.oddou I've edited my answer with an example of the iterator you proposed. Regarding your other concern, I suppose it depends on the definition of ad-hoc with what design you're comparing it against. Nim is still in development, and maybe the maintainers would appreciate a RFC on this matter, if it's something that would align with their design goals.

Comment: an RFC like this : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2026 ? really, they use those ?

Comment: More like [this](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/7337), which is an RFC involving the stdlib on their GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: Pitching in about this missing from the stdlib. It isn't really ad-hoc when you are comparing two otherwise different data-types. HashTables are used to have fast lookup on a key, while HashSets are made to have sets of values. So why would the tables module have a set difference procedure in it? It might make a bit more sense for the sets module to have it, but it's still not obviously something that should be there.

Comment: @PMunch it is ad-hoc to make a procedure that does a set difference between a HashTable and a Set. C++ solves this using type erasure. You pass iterator ranges to algorithms (not containers), and therefore the stdlib covers this case simply by being generic. This is the Unix philosophy where little bricks can spawn emergent features by combination.